# Options Of dropdown are not populating

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core

## Title: Cascading Dropdown Issue in ASP.NET Core with AJAX (404 Error)

`Description:

I'm working on a project that requires implementing cascading dropdowns in ASP.NET Core using AJAX. The goal is to create three dropdowns for Country, State, and City, where selecting a country should populate the corresponding states and selecting a state should display the related cities.

I've set up the controller to handle AJAX requests and configured the view with the necessary HTML and JavaScript. However, I'm encountering a 404 error when attempting to fetch states and cities using AJAX.`

`Controller Code (Extract from LecturerController):-`

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Lecturers/GetStatesByCountry/{CountryID}")]
        public IActionResult GetStatesByCountry(int CountryID)
        {
            // Replace this with your logic to fetch states based on the countryID.
            List<State> states = dbAccessLayer.GetStatesByCountryID(CountryID);

            // Convert the list of states to a format that can be easily serialized to JSON.
            var stateList = states.Select(s => new { Key = s.StateID, Value = s.StateName });

            return Json(stateList);
        }


        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Lecturers/GetCitiesByState/{StateID}")]
        public JsonResult GetCitiesByState(int StateID)
        {
            List<StudentP.Models.City> cities = dbAccessLayer.GetCitiesByStateID(StateID);
            var cityList = cities.Select(c => new { Key = c.CityID, Value = c.CityName }).ToList();
            return Json(cityList);
        }
```

`View Code:-`

```
@model StudentP.Models.LecturersModel
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Lecturers", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Create Lecturer</title>
        <!-- Include Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link id="theme-link" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-+w5jrxF5Tl2M9z6zweF98Cc5wPwP71A66f+OWiv60lgG1G9HjGjznfcLB8/aVvIs2hTfbj7z3VQgBEN8SP6KYg==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <!-- Include Font Awesome CSS for icons -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-ApNbghDs4vEX71nKGjW1rBq2v3Qxss3q5Dx9juYbfc4z3P8h6blVpz3x8M8A2FpxsdzU+Uug7c3dDlPZZXnZ6Lw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

        <!-- Your custom CSS styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="your-custom-styles.css" />

        <!-- Dark Mode Toggle Button -->
        <style>
            /* Define a custom dark mode class */
            body {
                transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
                position: relative;
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc, #333);
                color: #eee;
            }

            body.dark-mode {
                background: #333;
                color: #fff;
            }

            #dark-mode-toggle {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 20px;
                right: 20px;
                z-index: 9999;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container mt-5">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <a class="minimal-button" asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
                    <a class="minimal-button" href="javascript:history.back();">Back</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1>Create Lecturer</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <form asp-action="Create">
                        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="LastName" class= "control-label">Last Name</label>
                            <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryID, "Country")
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryID, ViewBag.Country as SelectList, "Select Country", new { @class = "form-control", id = "CountryID" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateID, "State")
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateID, ViewBag.States as SelectList, "Select State", new { @class = "form-control", id = "StateID" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityID, "City")
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityID, ViewBag.Cities as SelectList, "Select City", new { @class = "form-control", id = "CityID" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block" href="javascript:history.back();">Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Dark Mode Toggle Button -->
            <button id="dark-mode-toggle" class="btn btn-primary">Toggle Dark Mode</button>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha512-d7I2WYT6F3RM1fD0dJ7b5AO0MvtA0bB9zTj16QKrq5KJDONBZg4z8lqrV5k3F/C6q0fs17IC3UZ5Yb4OgYms6tZw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" integrity="sha512-6cXGp4d5PzR0eC+ZvApK1xID5Vy2XsXpB53dJPMTvIv/yzHzpk2Oi8gY4pF3x67bH7aGrb1a0ir8uG1mYcqr/Xw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js" integrity="sha512-AGV1fOtuAX+IiWXaemgak5tuU0+hh5+dPCa6Z6FgsqEq/UJGn3+nIO91MVp2g69sMWHdF/VtTa9/i7s7Q9/66w==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>

        @section scripts {
        <script>
            function updateStateDropdown() {
                var selectedCountry = document.getElementById("CountryID").value;
                var stateDropdown = document.getElementById("StateID");

                // Clear the current options in the State dropdown
                stateDropdown.innerHTML = "";

                // Make an AJAX request to fetch the states based on the selected country
                $.get(`/Lecturers/GetStatesByCountry/${selectedCountry}`, function (data) {
                    // Create an option for each state
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.value = data[i].Key;
                        option.text = data[i].Value;
                        stateDropdown.appendChild(option);
                    }

                    // Clear the city dropdown
                    var cityDropdown = document.getElementById("CityID");
                    cityDropdown.innerHTML = '<option value="">Select City</option>';
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("Error fetching states: " + errorThrown);
                });
            }

            function updateCityDropdown() {
                var selectedState = document.getElementById("StateID").value;
                var cityDropdown = document.getElementById("CityID");

                // Make an AJAX request to fetch the cities based on the selected state
                $.get(`/Lecturers/GetCitiesByState/${selectedState}`, function (data) {
                    cityDropdown.innerHTML = '<option value="">Select City</option>';
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        var option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.value = item.Key;
                        option.text = item.Value;
                        cityDropdown.appendChild(option);
                    });
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("Error fetching cities: " + textStatus);
                });
            }

            document.getElementById("CountryID").addEventListener("change", updateStateDropdown);
            document.getElementById("StateID").addEventListener("change", updateCityDropdown);

            // Initial update when loading the page
            updateStateDropdown();
            updateCityDropdown();
        </script>
    }

    </body>
    </html>
}
```

`The issue seems to be related to the AJAX requests. I suspect that there might be an issue with the URLs used in the AJAX requests. When I select a country from the dropdown, I encounter a 404 error, and the same happens when I select a state.

Notably, when I select "India" in the dropdown, it populates three "undefined" options, even though there are three states for India in the database.

I'm relatively new to programming, so any guidance or suggestions on resolving this issue and successfully implementing cascading dropdowns would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!`

Comment: `@html.beginform` creates a form tags in place of it's brackets so it should be within the body tag - probably in place of where you have `<form asp-action="Create"></form>`

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging.  First, always inspect the HTML *as rendered* to ensure your `@Html.` lines are generating the HTML you're expecting.   Next, debug the variables as you get them, eg `console.log("selectedCountry", selectedCountry);`  Then check the browser network tab to see exactly what url is being requested that's giving the 404

Comment: The Html.BeginForm helper in ASP.NET MVC generates the <form> tags directly in the HTML, and it should be used within the <body> of the HTML document. You don't need to manually add <form> tags when using Html.BeginForm.

Comment: I tried using console.log for country and i am getting expected output. Still same issue

Comment: If you are doing this on initial load rather than on update of one of the other dropdowns, why not just do it server side and pass it in the model

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 0):

I test your code and reproduce it, you can try to change

```
 option.value = data[i].Key;
 option.text = data[i].Value;
 option.value = item.Key;
 option.text = item.Value;
```

into:

```
option.value = data[i].key;
option.text = data[i].value;
option.value = item.key;
option.text = item.value;
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Sashank , any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?